# cakephp 2.0 Fatal error: Call to a member function sort() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp

Trying to be as specific as possible, as I got slammed last time I posted something!

Users authenticate and then in AppController I route them to a controller called Owners with the action being index code below

```
    public $components = array(                                                                         
  'Session',                                                                                    
  'Auth' => array(                                                                              
    'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Owners', 'action' => 'index')                     
)
```

I am new to Cake, but my guess is when the Owner Controller fires the code in the index function, it returns nothing and that is why I get the fatal error message in the view. 
(I am reading the Cakephp 2.0 cookbook) and yes there are several Owners in the owner table so its not empty.

mysql> select * from owners;
+----+-----------+-------------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------+-------+-------
------+---------+------------+-------------+
| id | firstname | middlename  | lastname | streetaddress      | city     | zipcode | state | phonen
umber | user_id | vehicle_id | citation_id |
+----+-----------+-------------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------+-------+-------
------+---------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | Mark      | Walter      | Simpson  | 1234 Anytown       | antonw   | 12345   | Ge    | 916123
456   |       1 |       NULL |        NULL |
|  2 | Frank     | Dorthmuller | Frank    | 2878 Bonlay Street | Fresno   | 95758   | Ca    | 916551
0234  |       3 |       NULL |        NULL |
|  3 | Toren     | W           | Valone   | 8252 blind oak way | Belfower | 3889    | ca    | 917838
8     |       1 |       NULL |        NULL |
|  4 | Toren     | W           | Valone   | 8252 blind oak way | Belfower | 3889    | ca    | 917838
8     |       1 |       NULL |        NULL |
+----+-----------+-------------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------+-------+-------
------+---------+------------+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

In the Owners controller I put this following code in the index function,

```
     public function index() {                                                                   

          $this->set('owners', $this->Owner->find('all'));                                      
    }
```

When I login as a user I get this, 
Owners

Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Paginator [CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 804]

Fatal error: Call to a member function sort() on a non-object in /srv/www/www.cross-town-traffic-software.com/public_html/freecite/app/View/Owners/index.ctp on line 5

Here is line five from the index.ctp file in the owners directory

```
<th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id');?></th>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the PaginatorHelper in your view, but have not included it.

Add

```
public $helpers = array('Paginator');
```

to your controller. [See Cookbook for background on Helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html) and how to use them in your views.

Comment: So when you override the index function you have to add the paginator helper? Now I am getting Warning (2): array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given and  Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /srv/www/www.cross-town-traffic-software.com/public_html/freecite/app/View/Owners/index.ctp on line 19

Comment: When I remove the index function from the controller and put the scaffolding back in, then i get a page with all the owners and actions. I did leave the helpers in, and got no error message.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `index()` function, `$helpers` is a member of your Controller class, just like `$components`. If you want to use a helper in a view, you need to include it in the corresponding controller. That's all. About your next error message: It's pretty hard to tell, without seeing line 19 of your file...

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you have to add

```
public $components = array('Paginator');
```

instead of

```
public $helpers = array('Paginator');
```